# nodejs can't loop the array object

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to get some data from firebase and put it in an `Array`, the value in question is `listquestion`. For debugging I tried to show it using  `listquestion.map` but it's not showing anything but if I look at my console, the `Array` has 3 objects inside it. I'm assuming the error is when I trying to put the data in the array but I did not find how to fix it

```
export function onceGetQuestion() {
  var listquestion = [
    {
      answercount: "",
      question: "",
      status: ""
    }
  ];

  db.ref("questions")
    .once("value")
    .then(function(snaps) {
      const foo = snaps.val();
      if (foo !== null) {
        Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
          db.ref("questions")
            .child(key)
            .once("value")
            .then(function(snap) {
              var questionlist = listquestion;
              questionlist.push({
                answercount: snap.val().answercount,
                question: snap.val().question,
                status: snap.val().status
              });
              listquestion = questionlist;
            });
        });
      }
    });
  console.log(listquestion);
  return listquestion;
```

front end (react )

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      listquestion: [],
      done: undefined
    };
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.state.listquestion = db.onceGetQuestion();
  }
  render() {
    return (
       questions.map(function(position, i){
         ........ 
       <span >{position.question}</span>
         ........
    }
.......
```

the array : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL7zM.jpg

Comment: Where is `questions` declared and assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the callback. When you call

```
Object.keys(foo).forEach(key => {
          db.ref("questions")
            .child(key)
            .once("value")
            .then(function(snap) {
              var questionlist = listquestion;
              questionlist.push({
                answercount: snap.val().answercount,
                question: snap.val().question,
                status: snap.val().status
              });
              listquestion = questionlist;
            });
```

even if `listquestion` have been declare in the global scope of your function, the value that you assign inside the `.then` are local so the value stop existing when you leave the `.then`

So you have to do whatever treatment needed inside the `.then`.

A possible solution would be to return the promise (`db.ref("questions").once("value")`) from your `onceGetQuestion()` function. Create a method in your class for the treatment (it would be the code inside the `then` in your original solution). call the method `.then` of the value returned from your function and in this context (the `.then`) change the state of your class using `this.setState({})`

A comment pointed out a very good answer about asynchronous calls:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593/12016897

ref: https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html